# PHP Remove all hyperlinks of specific domain and subdomain

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to Remove all hyper links of specific domain and sub domain from text..
Here is what I am trying

```
$link = '<a href="http://www.my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> with www </a> 
        example <a href="http://my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> No www </a>
        <a href="http://www.subdomain.my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> Subdomain</a>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> yahoo</a> ';
$pattern1 = '|<a [^>]*href="http://www.my.com(.*)">(.*)</a>|iU';
$str = preg_replace($pattern1, "\\2", $link);
 echo $str
```

Ok I just want to remove all domains+subdomains for my.com but yahoo.com should not be removed.
I am getting output of only 1st link removed rest all there

Comment: try /sui modificators in your pattern

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` and `XPath`.

Comment: @VitKos it remove all text of my.com+link ... and yahoo.com like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does a small job:

```
<?php
$link = '<a href="http://www.my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> with www </a> 
        example <a href="http://my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> No www </a>
        <a href="http://www.subdomain.my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> Subdomain</a>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> yahoo</a> ';
$pattern1 = '|<a href="http://(www\..*)?my.com(.*)">(.*)</a>|iU';
$str = preg_replace($pattern1, "\\3", $link);

echo "<textarea style=\"width:700px; height:90px;\">"
  . $str
  . "</textarea>";
?>
```

Gives:

```
with www  
    example  No www 
     Subdomain
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> yahoo</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$link = '<a href="http://www.my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> with www </a> 
    example <a href="http://my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> No www </a>
    <a href="http://www.subdomain.my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> Subdomain</a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> yahoo</a> ';
$pattern1 = '~([<]a\s+href="http\:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*(my\.com)([^>]*["][>])(.*)(</a>)~i';
// I'm not sure if you want to keep the text or not, but if you do not
// want to keep it, remove $3 from the next line (so it's now '' instead):
$replacement = '$3';
$str = preg_replace($pattern1, $replacement, $link);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$link = '<a href="http://www.my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> with www </a> 
        example <a href="http://my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> No www </a>
        <a href="http://www.subdomain.my.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> Subdomain</a>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/app/319354212" class="hh"> yahoo</a> ';
$replacement_string = "replacement string";
$new_url = preg_replace('/<a href\s*=\s*(\"|\')(http\:\/\/www\.|http\:\/\/).*my\.com.*>.*<\/a>/', '', $link);
print $new_url;

?>
```

Comment: this remove www. and without www with there text ... and subdomain is still there with link and text

Comment: Why are you using `/` as delimiter?

Comment: @harry thx - yes its working but its removing all text also .... i just want to remove links not text